# Need help in multiple LoadBalancer and multiple Ingress and multiple domain-names in GKE ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have successfully setup GKE Cluster using GKE Ingress for both developer and production env in a different Project name through Github Action (CI/CD).

Explaining in details

```
1. And in 7 deployment im using for 7 all --> readinessProbe/livenessProbe/startupProbe, env variables, resources/requests/limits.
2. And in 7 service(svc) im using for 7 all --> type: ClusterIP
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Jux.png)
3. And in 7 ingress im using for 7 all --> ingressClassName: "gce", kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name, networking.gke.io/managed-certificates and comes to rules
    - host: "ui.cloudnetwork.in"
    - host: "backend.cloudnetwork.in"
    - host: "backend-eng.cloudnetwork.in"
    - host: "test-svc.cloudnetwork.in"
    - host: "test-course.cloudnetwork.in"
    - host: "test-contact.cloudnetwork.in"
    - path: /* --> to all 7 i given same 
      backend:
             service:
                name: ui
                port:
                   number: 8080
     backend:
             service:
                name: backend
                port:
                   number: 8080 
  
     backend:
             service:
                name: backend-eng
                port:
                   number: 8080 
    backend:
             service:
                name: test-svc
                port:
                   number: 8080
   backend:
             service:
                name: test-course
                port:
                   number: 3000
   backend:
             service:
                name: test-contact
                port:
                   number: 3000

Optional only for Ingress defaultBackend (I didn't use this just sharing whether to use this or not)
 spec:
   defaultBackend:
     service:
       name: ui
         port:
         number: 8080

Optional only for backendconfig (I didn't use this just sharing whether to use this or not)

apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
 kind: BackendConfig
 metadata:
   name: ui
   namespace: cloudnetwork
 spec:
   healthCheck:
     timeoutSec: 1
     type: HTTP
     requestPath: /
     port: 8080
```

Ingress also have 7 external/public IP address  that mapped to above 7 domain name that register in godaddy in A records
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwT1s.png)
ManagedCertificate
4. I used google managed certificate for 7 after 3 months it will expire but i don't know to whether it will renew automatically or manually i need to renew it that still i need look on it

5. And also we are using 7 Health checks that connect to 7 services (svc)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICMEL.png)
6. And also we are using 3 Network endpoint group( Zonal NEGs) for each all 7 services (svc) that means 21 Zonal NEG total we using that ingress gke create that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU7ak.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf9ZT.png)

its all running having 2 replicas for each deployment that mean total 14 pods are running.

My Question is can i use multiple ingress and multiple load balancer and multiple domain names i know cost will be high when we use multiple load balancer

I want to know do we have any alternate solution instead of using multiple load balancer, domain names and ingress

Only i need to ui domain name reset all 6 services can have service name or anything

why i used domain name is that because its ui service is talk to backend service and then backend talk to backend.eng service that one on one depends in-between we have DB also after backend service.

Sample for one ui.yaml sharing u and same i used for 6 service

```
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "ui"
  namespace: "cloudnetwork"
  labels:
    app: "ui"
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "ui"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "ui"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "ui"
        image: "xxxxxxxxxx:2024-02-22-1334"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        readinessProbe:
           httpGet:
             path: /
             port: 8080
           initialDelaySeconds: 30
           periodSeconds: 5
        livenessProbe:
           httpGet:
             path: /
             port: 8080
           initialDelaySeconds: 30
           periodSeconds: 5
        startupProbe:
           httpGet:
             path: /
             port: 8080
           initialDelaySeconds: 30
           failureThreshold: 0
           periodSeconds: 10
        env:
        - name: "BACKEND_URL"
          value: "https://backend.cloudnetwork.in" 
        resources:
          requests: # Minimum amount of resources requested
             cpu: 200m
             memory: 512M
          limits: # Maximum amount of resources requested
             cpu: 500m
             memory: 1024M
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ui
  namespace: cloudnetwork
  labels:
   app: webui
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: ui
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
---
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: ingress-ui
   namespace: cloudnetwork
   annotations:
     ingressClassName: "gce"
     kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ingress-ui
     networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert-ui
 spec:
   rules: 
   - host: "ui.cloudnetwork.in"
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /*
         pathType: ImplementationSpecific
         backend:
             service:
                name: ui
                port:
                   number: 8080 
---
This is option i didnt use but if need or this one is better then  i will use it
# apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
# kind: Ingress
# metadata:
#   name: ingress-ui
#   namespace: cloudnetwork
#   annotations:
#     kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ingress-ui
#     networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert-ui
#     ingressClassName: "gce"
# spec:
#   defaultBackend:
#     service:
#       name: ui
#       port:
#         number: 8080                   
---
# apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
# kind: ManagedCertificate
# metadata:
#  name: managed-cert-ui
#  namespace: cloudnetwork
# spec:
#  domains:
#    - ui.cloudnetwork.in
---
This is option i didnt use but if need or this one is better then  i will use it
# apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
# kind: BackendConfig
# metadata:
#   name: ui
#   namespace: cloudnetwork
# spec:
#   healthCheck:
#     timeoutSec: 1
#     type: HTTP
#     requestPath: /
#     port: 8080
```

Above all i deploy in PROD env is up and running
i dont want to take any risk on prod purpose and also want to save COST